# Connection Dialog does not appear in Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When I open my Management Studio program, it does not open up the connection dialog like it used to. It gives me a dialog box which says:

> Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.

Anyone got any idea how to fix this?

[image: Error Dialog]

Comment: Do you have any dodgy extensions installed? Also I believe those bottom left buttons allow you to drill down and get more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of SQL server is this?

Review some of the possible solutions here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c588b06e-7002-40ba-bf59-7e7c9decaf23/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-unable-to-finish-the-sql-2012-installation-on

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/718182/management-studio-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object

Answer (score 1):

When the Management Studio initializes, it opens a modal connection dialog box that for some reason is not accessible.

The solution is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> which will close the dialog box.  When you click Connect in Management Studio, it will now open the dialog in the middle of the Management Studio window.